# onCleanUp() vs onComplete() vs afterLaunch()

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

In Protractor, there is a "global set up" method called `onPrepare()`, but I'm not completely sure what is meant to be a "global tear down" - there are three relevant methods: `onCleanUp`, `onComplete` and `afterLaunch` that are all called after a test execution.

*Why* does `protractor` have three methods called after a test run? What is the difference between `onCleanUp`, `onComplete` and `afterLaunch`?

---

I've also noticed that there is an *"exit" event* that we can attach a callback to ([example here](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/blob/master/src/index.js#L64)):

```
protractor.on('exit', function (status) {

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onComplete` will be executed once per capability after all tests have finished, but the webdriver instance has not yet been shut down.

`onCleanup` will be executed once per capability after all tests have finished and the webdriver instance has been shut down

`afterLaunch` will be executed only once before program exits; after all capabilities are finished (after all `onCleanup`)

Further information on protractor callback functions can be found in [their GitHub documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L455).

Comment: Could you please add more details on which use cases each of the methods covers? Also, how does the "exit" event fit here? Thank you!